# Is it possible to embed a Tweet / Twitter Card natively in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, native

Is it possible to embed a Tweet / Twitter Card (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards/types/summary-card) natively in an iOS App? All I could find was an API that delivers the data:

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/show.json?id=210462857140252672

See https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/show/%3Aid

Then I would be able to construct my own UIView representing a Twitter Card, but isn´t there something 'official' to display Twitter Cards in a more native way than HTML in apps?

Cheers,
Marc

Comment: No, the current API level access to Twitter in iOS does not include presentation of card objects. You'll need to roll your own as you described.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter offers an official way to display tweets natively in iOS through `TwitterKit`:
https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/ios/show-tweets